# How to use AND in hibernate 5.2 Criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have two objects `User` and `House`. One user can have several houses.

Annotations from `House.class`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="house")
public class House {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="house_id")
private int id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user;

@Column(name="country")
private String country;

@Column(name="city")
private String city;

@Column(name="street")
private String street;

@Column(name="post_code")
private String postCode;

@Column(name="house_number")
private String houseNumber;

@Column(name="flats")
private int flats;

@Column(name="picture")
private String picture;

@Column(name="surname_first") // order names will be written in receipt
private Boolean writeSurnameFirst;

@Column(name="cut_name") // Nado ili net sokrashat imena
private Boolean cutName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="currency_id")
private Currency currency;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="documentation_lang_id")
private Languages documentationLang;

@Column(name="default_house")
private Boolean defaultHouse;
```

I need to get a `House` object based on `User` and column `defaultHouse = true`.

I tried this code, but I can't get how to implement `User` into it:

```
tx = sess.beginTransaction();
// create criteria builder
CriteriaBuilder builder = sess.getCriteriaBuilder();
// create criteria
CriteriaQuery<House> query = builder.createQuery(House.class);
// specify criteria root
Root<House> root = query.from(House.class);
query.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("default_house"), true)
     .and(builder.equal(root.get(House.getUser), user)));
house = sess.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
tx.commit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact `builder.and()` takes two parameters which are the two restrictions to be joined with `AND` keyword in SQL, and the `builder.and()` should be used inside `builder.where()` method.

change the following code:

```
query.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("default_house"), true)
     .and(builder.equal(root.get(House.getUser), user)));
```

Like this:

```
query.select(root).where(builder.and(builder.equal(root.get("default_house"),  true), builder.equal(root.get(House.getUser), user))));
```

Please refer to [**Hibernate ORM 5.2.11.Final User Guide**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-from-multiple-root-example) for further details and more examples.

**Note:**

`Hibernate` is concerned about objects and not tables and when we use its modules like `Criteria` we use attributes names in the Object and not DB columns names.

Answer (score 0):

In CriteriaBuilder methods you must use the entity field names like following:

```
builder.equal(root.get("defaultHouse"), true)
```

and not the database column names:

```
builder.equal(root.get("default_house"), true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I attached my example:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Eje> query = builder.createQuery(Eje.class);
Root<Eje> productRoot = query.from(Eje.class);

query.select(productRoot)
     .where(builder.and(builder.equal(productRoot.get("id"), 1),                    builder.equal(productRoot.get(Eje_.factorCriticos).get(FactorCritico_.id), 1)));

result =(List<T>) session.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```